# Angular with Bootstrap for responsive website

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm new to angular with a background of bootstrap.
I'm trying to mix both to get the best, but many articles do not recommend that.

I liked Angular for:

1. MVC structure
2. less code
3. More organized

I liked Bootstrap for:

1. easy to use.
2. available templates and resources.
3. responsive.
4. plenty of components ready to use for websites.
5. can be used with jQuery to add fantastic animation and live to the website.

My question:
Is it OK to mix Angular + bootstrap + Jquery + JS in my website project?
Or am I missing some resources for angular that gives me the same results without this combination?

I hope I didn't waste your time with a beginner question.
But I hope you help me to decide the right and overcome my hesitation.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good to mix bootstrap+jQuery with Angular. If you want to use bootstrap, take a look at [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), without jQuery.

Comment: Is it enough to provide the same components of bootstrap with a responsive theme? and could be used with angular elements?

Comment: You can take a look, it provides a lot of components but not all. And yes, it is responsive. With angular elements you can use any type of theming framework. I suggest you to take a look at Angular Material too: https://material.angular.io/

Comment: Appreciate your patience and support